# general hypersurface section of a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $C$ is smooth projective curve in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Then the general position theorem says that points in a general hyperplane section of $C$ are in linearly general position.

Question: Is there any such result for a general hypersurface section ?